# Error with "predict" function, when creating predictions for Keras Deep Neural Network in R

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, prediction

So I've created some Deep Neural Network regression models with my own data using Keras in R. When I created the models close to a year ago, I'm almost certain that I did not get these errors, and it seems that no matter how I structure or manipulate the data, I get the same exact error, so I'm unsure if its an issue with my code or just the program.

When I fit the models, it works, and when I plug in the validation data, it clearly works and shows the difference in the validation data and the training data, so I'm unsure why I keep getting this error message about not being able to predict the model. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, thank you!

Full Error Message:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "keras_training_history"
```

Full Example of Code Setup:

```
#Load Libraries
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)
library(caTools)
library(tfruns)
library(caret)

#Creating Full Data Set
FDS1 <- OB1 %>% left_join(.,OB2, by="VAR1") %>% mutate(VAR2=if_else(VAR3 > VAR4,"1","0")) %>% na.exclude() %>% select(., -VAR5)

#Converting Variables:
FDS1$VAR3 <- as.factor(MWC18$VAR3)
FDS1$VAR4 <- as.factor(MWC18$VAR4)
FDS1$VAR8 <- as.factor(MWC18$VAR8)

#Creating One-Hot Encoding
dummy1<- dummyVars(" ~ .", data=FDS1)
DFDS1 <- data.frame(predict(dummy1, newdata = FDS1)) 

#Creating Subset
SUB1<- DFDS1 %>% select(.,-VAR9,-VAR10,-VAR11) %>% relocate(.,VAR14) 

#Setup for KERAS Deep Neural Network 
sample1<-sample.split(SUB1[,1],SplitRatio=.75)
train1<-subset(SUB1,sample1==TRUE)%>%as.matrix()
test1<-subset(SUB1,sample1==FALSE)%>%as.matrix()

#Creating Train & Test Sets for X&Y
y_train_1<-train1[,1]
y_test_1<-test1[,1]
x_train_1<-train1[,-1] 
x_test_1<-test1[,-1] 


#Creating DEEP NEURAL NETWORK W/ KERAS
DNN_1<- keras_model_sequential()
DNN_1 %>%
  layer_dense(units = 30,
              input_shape = c(59))%>% layer_dropout(0.2)%>% 
  layer_dense(units = 15 ,
              activation = "elu")%>% layer_dropout(0.2)%>%
  layer_dense(units = 8 ,
              activation = "relu")%>% layer_dropout(0.2)%>%
  layer_dense(name = "OutputLayer",
              units = 1)

#Compliling Model
DNN_1 %>% compile(loss = "mean_absolute_error",
                                  optimizer = "adam",
                                  metrics = c("mean_absolute_error"))
#Fitting Model
FIT_DNN1<-DNN_1%>%fit(x_train_1,y_train_1,epoch=50,batchsize=4,validation_data=list(x_test_1,y_test_1),verbose=2)

#Prediction Model
pred <- FIT_DNN1 %>% predict(x_test_1)

#Error Message
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "keras_training_history"
```

I was expecting to create predictions based off the test data, but it keeps saying that I can't create predictions with the data in that form. I'm unsure how "Keras_training_history" is an issue when I've tried several different ways to present the test data that matched the format of the test data.

Does anyone know what aspect of the process the error message is even referring to? (I self-taught myself Keras and have struggled with Error Messages) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just had the same issue. It seems in this case the predict function wants your compiled lstm. Have you tried to do:

pred <- DNN1 %>% predict(x_test_1)

?

see also
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/04/lstm-network-in-r/

In my understanding you need to train the model in order to see (you can plot the fitted object) the loss function and optimizer. So Keras' fit() does not return the model but it returns a History object.  "The returned history object holds a record of the loss values and metric values during training" - see here https://keras.io/guides/training_with_built_in_methods/.

But I am not sure. I was going to ask you whether you solved this issue... But I didn't find the comment button.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. In future please try to avoid asking questions in your answer, instead seek clarification using comments first, and then compose your answer once you are more sure of whether it solves the problem.